# matplotlib animations from a remote hosted ipython notebook

Tags: animation, matplotlib, ssh, ipython, jupyter

My home desktop is the guts of my workstation (good CPU + memory). I often ssh in from my chromebook and port forward ipython notebooks in order to work remotely.

However, I have run into issues with displaying matplotlib animations remotely (static plots work fine). The animation appears as a static image. (The same code creates an animated plot when run on the host machine.) I know the animation is working as I can save it off into an MP4 (and the video is correct).

My current workaround is to save the video as an MP4, push it to my github page, then download the MP4 on my chromebook, and use the chrome os's native video player. **This workaround sucks!**

Does anybody have a solution to view animated plots in a remote hosted ipython notebook? 
Or does anybody have an improvement to my current workaround?

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time
from IPython.core.display import clear_output,display

f,ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=1)
plt.xlim(0,10)
plt.ylim(0,100)
for i in range(10):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    clear_output(wait=True)
    ax.plot(i,i**2,'bo')
    display(f) 

plt.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Because I am using the  funcAnim method, I cannot use 'display'. I will update question with code snippet.